# Taking input from barcode reader for isbn db search

Tags: python, barcode, barcode-scanner

I tried to have an input in python from my barcode scanner to extract the isbn code of books (13 numbers), unfortunately it opens a tab/window, both in the code area and in the shell. 
The tab is the "tabify region" Alt+F5, allowing to enter tabulation (Tab width) in the code or in the shell, in the box are printed the 12 last numbers. (tabify in Format/Tabify region).

I don't know how that window is opened everytime I trigger the scanner ?
Will I have to use something like Pyusb to have it work properly ?

The 13 digits of the code bar is well printed in notepad, openoffice, webbrowser

I'm using python 3.4.1 IDLE on windows 7
I'm using a zebex barecode-reader, it was set as usb keyboard, international, with ENTER at end of scanning, and on other tests Nothing at end of scanning

thank you.

Comment: Apparently your barcode reader is pretending to be a keyboard (which is fine) and sending Alt-F5 at the beginning of a new barcode. The question is not so much a programming question as a configuration question about your barcode reader. If you cannot configure it, write a program that accepts Alt-F5 as input and treats it as the signal that a barcode is coming (and run that program outside an IDE that uses Alt-F5 for its own purposes).

Comment: I have to add that it writes down the first number then launch the alt+f5 tab with the rest of them. I will check if I can make it exclude that part but I'm not sure if that's alt+f5 that triggers that window.
Thanks for the insight

Comment: Did you ever find this out? Just got myself a Zebex and looking around for solutions